# Angular UI-Select limitTo and preload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I'm using Angular UI-Select for lookups but the performance sucks when the collection becomes longer and longer.

To overcome this problem I put a limitTo filter (15 items) on my `repeat` this is a workable option but the problem I now face is that when I load the page and the value inside my `ng-model` is outside of the first lets say 15 items inside my repeat i will end up with an empty dropdown list. I know that this is a problem and there are open issues about it on github but i hope someone can shed some light on this or can tell me a workable solution for this... If that means to change the javascript of UI-Select I willing to take the risk because i don't have the idea UI-Select team is fixing it soon...

The version of UI-Select I use is `0.12.1`

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days trying a lot of different ways to get my preloading with the limitTo working. I decided to build my own custom limitTo filter.

This filter does exactly the same as the angular limitTo filter but i will pass the model to it so i am able to look for that item in the list of all items and union it with the items that are done by the standard limit to...

I think it's pretty neat.

Comment: can you share your custom filter?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone's still looking for the solution.
 This custom limitTo filter removes the selected items before limiting the list. This is a simplified version of [angular's limitTo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js#L3) (it simply assumes you are passing in the right values).

```js
angular
  .module('app')
  .filter('myLimitTo', myLimitToFilter);


/*========================================
 =                 filter                =
 ========================================*/
function myLimitToFilter() {
  return function (input, limit, selectedItems) {

    if (!_.isArray(input) && !_.isString(input)) {
      return input;
    }

    if (limit >= 0) {
      return input.filter(filterOutExisting).slice(0, limit);
    } else {
      return input.slice(limit, input.length);
    }

    function filterOutExisting(item) {
      return !_.includes(selectedItems, item);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: is this using angular-underscore or something ? I get "ReferenceError: _ is not defined" when trying to use your filter